# Is there a halachic prohibition with naming a child Iyov?

Tags: halacha, names

I've heard that it's not good to name after someone who has suffered bad mazel, but are there any halachic prohibitions against it? It apparently means "persecuted" but Miriam means "bitter" so they don't all need to have pleasant meanings, right? I really appreciate the message of remaining faithful even when it isn't easy. Just wondering!

Comment: I'm not aware of any halachicly prohibited names. Is anyone else?

Comment: @doubleAA http://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.38b.4/he/Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Is that a prohibition? The OP already knows "that it's not good to name after someone who has suffered bad mazel"

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Nechama! Thanks for sharing the question. Consider reading this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775) to the site. It notes the importance of adding sources where possible. In this case, while the question is ok, it could be strengthened with some link or reference to the issue you mention of naming after a person with bad mazal. This helps users investigate whether or not it is an actual prohibition.

Comment: @DoubleAA mis-read the question. I thought she wanted to know if one should avoid naming children after people who suffered (and weren't just evil - though Iyov was arguably evil).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin why was Iyov evil? I've never heard that.

Comment: @NechamaEsther See http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: And further....

Comment: I edited the title to better match the question. If you don't like this edit, you can roll it back (after clicking the edit button). Using the edit button you can also add any other edits

Comment: there was a medakdek called ben yiov

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by 'halachic prohibition', but if you mean do halachic authorities rule that you shouldn't name after people who underwent certain negative experiences, the answer is yes. See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=192) for example. The reason behind it is that it could potentially harm the child, which would seem to be a more important consideration than any positive message expressed by the name. That being said, however, whether Iyov technically falls into that category is a separate question. Additionally, even if he does qualify as 'רוע מזליה', there may be ways around it, such as adding an additional name. A Rabbi should be consulted.

Comment: "if you mean do halachic authorities rule that you shouldn't name after people who underwent certain negative experiences" Is that really so? Seems to me there are halachic authorities who _say_ that you shouldn't name after people who underwent certain negative experiences. I don't see anyone ruling on a legal issue.

Comment: `The reason behind it is that it could potentially harm the child` Note however that many superstitions are forbidden or at least discouraged by Judaism. Erring on the side of superstition may not be merely useless, but may be counterproductive.

Comment: @DoubleAA The link is to Rabbi Feinsteins halachic responsa. Igros Moshe is a collection of halachic rulings of Rabbi Feinstein in his letters.

Comment: @Jay A book of responsa need not contain exactly 100% halachic rulings. You know that. Books of mathematics for example don't only contain theorems. They also contain best practices and tips. So too with the letters of rabbis. If you can find a legal issue in the letter that he ruled on, then mention it. Otherwise don't pretend there is one.

Comment: To clarify @DoubleAA's first comment, the OP is aware of a superstition regarding naming after those who suffered misfortune. The OP wasn't looking for this, but rather for some specific halakhic prohibition. All this answer does is reference one source that in turn cites other sources that were concerned enough with the superstition, that the source recommended that one avoid it "מן הראוי להקפיד". However that source does not state that there is any halakhic prohibition, besides for the superstition, which is what the OP asked about

Comment: @mevaqesh From the context of the rest of the question, it seems what the OP means by 'halachic prohibition' is some halachic consideration that would outweigh her preference for the name because of it's positive message. That's why until you edited it the title of the question was "is there anything wrong with naming a child Iyov". I believe I have found such a consideration in some poskim's assertion that one should not name under certain circumstances.

Comment: But you haven't provided a halachic consideration though. Just some thoughts of at least one rabbi.

Comment: @DoubleAA Regarding your point about Igros Moshe not being exclusively a book of halacha, I could be wrong but I think that they are all in fact halachic queries, including this one.

Comment: Even if every query is a halachik one that doesn't mean that everything in the book is a halachik ruling. You keep missing that. Every chapter heading in a math book may be about a theorem too.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I'm sure that sometimes he may go off on a non-halachic tangent in the course of his answers to halachic queries. But in this case it is not tangential at all, it is the direct response to the query, which was should  the child be named a certain way. I don't see how you can admit that the query was halachic but also maintain that the entire response is just advice. R. Feinstein would not devote an entire teshuva to non-halachic advice. Regarding the specific legal issue, he doesn't spell it out, but I imagine it would be the same as any case of causing harm to another person.

Comment: @Jay "R. Feinstein would not devote an entire teshuva to non-halachic advice." Huh? And why not?

Comment: @DoubleAA because, as far as I can tell, and from what I recall from the author's introduction, it's not that type of sefer, though I admit I haven't read every single teshuva. Are you aware of any other tshuvot that are entirely non-halachic that he included in his sefer?